# SAGA GIS segfaults on launch

Tags: qgis, gdal, ubuntu, saga

I'm having problems with **SAGA GIS**. It segfaults on launch, either from the command line or when called from QGIS.

If I run `saga_cmd` using gdb, I get this error:-

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /usr/bin/saga_cmd 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
____________________________

   #####   ##   #####    ##
  ###     ###  ##       ###
   ###   # ## ##  #### # ##
    ### ##### ##    # #####
 ##### #   ##  ##### #   ##
____________________________

SAGA Version: 2.2.7

[New Thread 0xb1dbbb40 (LWP 14864)]
[New Thread 0xb15bab40 (LWP 14865)]
[New Thread 0xafdb9b40 (LWP 14866)]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strlen_sse2_bsf () at ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/strlen-sse2-bsf.S:50
50  ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/strlen-sse2-bsf.S: No such file or directory.
```

My setup:-

- Ubuntu Tahr 32bit
- QGIS 2.16.3 . This is a fresh install. Using the standard QGIS install as [defined here](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu). This is the Stable release, and not UbuntuGIS.
- QGIS Running against GDAL/OGR 1.11.2.
- QGIS Compiled against GDAL/OGR 1.10.1
- SAGA 2.2.7

I found [this discussion](https://sourceforge.net/p/saga-gis/discussion/354013/thread/893c5b16/), which suggests it's the version of GDAL i'm using. This seems to tie in with when this problem first started - when GRASS 7 support started working for me from QGIS.

Is there a way around this? If GRASS and SAGA need different versions of GDAL, I'm worried that attempting to fixing this for SAGA might break GRASS 7 support, which I also need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yay! Found a solution...

- I used `sudo synaptic` to nuke all traces of SAGA from orbit (It's the only way to be sure..)
- I removed the line `deb ppa.launchpad.net.johanvdw/saga-gis/trusty/main` from my sources.lst (no offence to @johanvdw - your packaging got me up and running with SAGA with QGIS in the first place)
- reinstalled SAGA from the Ubuntu Software Centre.. I now have 2.1.4 installed

Now I can use SAGA from QGIS with no problems, and GRASS7 plugins work too.

```
____________________________

   #####   ##   #####    ##
  ###     ###  ##       ###
   ###   # ## ##  #### # ##
    ### ##### ##    # #####
 ##### #   ##  ##### #   ##
____________________________

SAGA Version: 2.1.4

Error: no arguments for saga call
Error: select a library
```